# how to get the number in a python string 

Tags: python

this is my code :

```
print int('adw第五代222')
```

it show error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 5, in <module>
    print int('adw第五代222')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'adw\xe7\xac\xac\xe4\xba\x94\xe4\xbb\xa3222'
```

what can i do ,

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> int(re.search('\d+', u'adw第五代222').group())
222
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to turn something that's not a number into an integer. So that's obviously not going to work. You will have to extract the digits from the string. If you don't want to use a regular expression, you could try something like this:

```
s = u'adw第五代222'
n = int(''.join(c for c in s if c.isdigit()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could go with something like:

```
class crazyint(int):
    def __new__(cls, arg=1):
        a = ''.join([x for x in arg if x.isdigit()])
        return int.__new__(cls, a)
```

.. which allows for crazyint('some234string434'). But I'd say this is more appropriate:

```
class crazyint(int):
    def __new__(cls, arg=1):
        print "whachu talkin' 'bout willis?"
```